# Why do React-Table column array objects have both camelCasing and PascalCasing

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am new to React and I've just started using React-Table.

I've noticed that in React-Table, when we define the columns array, the column object has Header, accessor, maxWidth, minResizeWidth, headerStyle, Cell, etc.

Header and Cell are uppercase, but the rest of the properties follow the camel case convention.

Is there a deeper meaning to this or is it just a mistake ?

E.g:

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: 'Store',
    accessor: 'storeName',
    minResizeWidth: 50,
    headerStyle: { textAlign: 'left' },
  },
  {
    Header: 'Current Rate',
    accessor: 'rate',
    maxWidth: 120,
  },
  {
    Header: 'Effective From',
    accessor: 'fromDate',
    Cell: renderDateCell,
    maxWidth: 120,
  },
];
```

Comment: Hi @r.net, could you mark the answer as correct if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties that you mention are called *renderers* in React-Table. As mentioned in the [React-Table documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#renderers), these *renderers* can be one of the following:

- A React Class
- JSX or any rendered react component
- Stateless functional component
- Function that returns any primitive

And because they can be user-defined components, they need to be uppercase, as elements that start with lowercase letters refer to built-in components in JSX. I suggest you take a look at [this part](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized) of the React documentation on JSX components for better clarification.

Comment: thanks that it does clarify, it had a meaning and not was not a mistake.